# normalizing graphs in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Suppose you have multiple graphs in a pgfplot whose y ranges are `[0 y1] [0 y2]` etc, `y1 < y2 <` .... I want to divide all graphs by `max(yi)`, so that the plot would be in the y range `[0 1]` (but maybe y axis range in `[0 1.2]` to have a nice display). 
In other words, I want to normalize the y axis, to compare the plots on a relative basis.

I used `scale y tick=manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1/120}}`, but it needs to know the maximum 120. Even if I put the correct maximum value, the plot is normalized to 
`[0 0.97]`. Is there a way to do it automatically, without having to look up data? Let's say I now which graph contains the maximum. There should be a simple solution to this.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, 
    xmax=4, 
    ymin=0, 
    ymax=3.2,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$]
\addplot[smooth,mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (0,2)
    (2,3)
    (3,1)
};
\addlegendentry{Case 1}

\addplot[smooth,color=red,mark=x]
    plot coordinates {
        (0,0)
        (1,1)
        (2,1)
        (3,2)
    };
\addlegendentry{Case 2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For instance, in this example I want to divide all y numbers divided by 3. The actual data file can be quite complicated; it's preferred that the pgfplots fins this maximum and normalizes all y axis by that.

Comment: Can you please add a full  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). This makes it much easier for people to help you. Having said this, without having seen you code, I suspect that the easiest way to do what you want is to scale the whole plot using `scale` (or `xscale` nad `yscale`).

Comment: Are you using tables for data supplement or closed formulas?

Comment: I am using data taken from files.